# How to locate Swift Foundation module location

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

In Xcode importing Foundation Framework helps to see all .h files implementation that are in Objective-C. But how can is see all the Foundation implementation files that are in Swift.

When I click with option on Array or String it takes me to the documentation, but it doesn't shows the actual location of the Array or String documentation.

Is there a way in Xcode to see all the Swift Foundation files documentation?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Documentation is documentation, wherever you see it. And have you tried `Cmd`-click instead of `Opt`-click?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Swift frameworks use [**module maps**](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html), not headers.

You can't see "all .h files" for `Swift.Array`, or `Swift.String`. There are none. They're all exported as a part of the *module* `Swift`.